# capture the screen using opengl, always black

Tags: c++, opengl

my projects needs to capture the screen image (partial screen) in realtime, The GDI way capturing screen works but slow and used too much resources. I then want to try using opengl glReadpixels to read the screen and save to the GPU memory (PBOs). I cannot use window capture since the application often changes windows layout and what I need is a fixed rectangular region.
I used the screen DC to generate the opengl context (the setpixel parts included produce black image (due to the window itself draws nothing but black, but on top of the window, there are other windows showing stuff of interest).

Here is partial of my code:

```
    void CMainWnd::setup_screencapture()
{


    hdcScr=::GetDC(NULL);
        ////searching hints that setpixelformat cannot be done to screen
//but if commented, no context will be able to generate.
        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pixelDesc =
        {
            sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
            1,
            PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW|PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL|
            PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
            PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
            24,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,0,0,0,
            32,//
            0,
            0,
            PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
            0,
            0,0,0
        };  

        int n_PixelFormat = ::ChoosePixelFormat(hdcScr,&pixelDesc);
        SetPixelFormat(hdcScr,n_PixelFormat,&pixelDesc);
        ///////////
        hglrcScr = wglCreateContext(hdcScr);

    //clean all buffers
    pbo_indx=0;
    max_num_pbos=100;
    num_frames_captured=0;
    for(int i=0;i<max_num_pbos;i++) pbo_scr_list[i]=0;
    pVideoBuffer=0;

    //the 
    //wglMakeCurrent(hdcScr,hglrcScr);
}

int CMainWnd::capture_screen()
{
    //capture limited rGlWin
    hptime t0;
    double dtime=t0.gettime();
    wglMakeCurrent(hdcScr,hglrcScr);
    screencapture_width=(rGlWin.right-rGlWin.left)/4*4;
    screencapture_height=(rGlWin.bottom-rGlWin.top)/4*4;
    if(!pbo_scr_list[pbo_indx])
    {
        glGenBuffersARB(1,&pbo_scr_list[pbo_indx]);
        glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,pbo_scr_list[pbo_indx]);
        glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,screencapture_width*screencapture_height*3,0,GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
        glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,0);
    }

    glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT); //read the backbuffer
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,pbo_scr_list[pbo_indx]); //link the buffer for pixel reading
    //gl read pixel uses the lower-left corner as 
    glReadPixels(rGlWin.left,rGlWin.bottom,screencapture_width,screencapture_height,GL_BGR,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,0); //unlink
    pbo_indx++;num_frames_captured++;
    if(pbo_indx>=max_num_pbos) pbo_indx=0;
    if(num_frames_captured>max_num_pbos) num_frames_captured=max_num_pbos;
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL,NULL);
    dtime=t0.gettime()-dtime;
    TRACE("screencapture time=%.2fms\n",dtime);
    return pbo_indx;
}
```

Simplifying the case: mainwnd is black and holds several child windows showing images, and I would like to capture a rect of the main window (with those children windows). I used screen DC to generate opengl context and it cannot get the correct screen. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot use OpenGL to capture the screen.

Comment: really? can you explain me a little bit more? or do you have any better approach?

Comment: As far as OpenGL concerned, any framebuffer content which you did not explictiely create by rendering to it via opengl, is completely undefined.

Comment: Well, `glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT); //read the backbuffer` certainly is not helping anything. You are reading the front-buffer, which in Windows Vista or newer, is pretty unreliable. Much of the time, the contents of the front-buffer are undefined immediately following a swap from back to front. You should make a point of reading the back-buffer (before to a buffer swap, because the back buffer may become undefined too if you wait until after).

Comment: But none of this matters when you're not drawing anything into your context. You may have windows on top of your render window, but they are separate things altogether. The window manager draws all of these things and you don't have access to the images produced by other windows. Your trick here basically only works when GDI is handling the desktop (Windows XP or older) - do not try this in modern versions of Windows.

Comment: GDI works on windows 7, but too slow. Any other method to achieve this purpose?

Comment: @shangping: The Windows Media API provides a special purpose video input / encoder device for capturing the screen. This would be your best bet (it's also what video streaming screen sharing applications use).

Comment: why not to render on a framebuffer and use that texture?

Comment: @datenwolf, thanks for the information, I will try windows media API

Comment: @mmostajab, I have thought of using FBO first, but I do not know how to combine different windows. Do you mean: I have a FBO associated to main window glcontext and let all other window update the colorbuffer attached to it? Kindly explain me more details, thanks. I still prefer using opengl if possible since it could be much faster using GPU's memory

Comment: @shangping I did not get your question exactly. But if you have different windows and want to show the content of one window in other one, you will have two contexts for two windows, and you are able to share a texture which will be used in framebuffer for rendering of the child windows. To combine them, you just need to also store the depth buffer for each child window and write the depth in main window while you are writing the child window results.

Comment: back to report progress: If I turned off the windows 7 transparency, the opengl can save the image without any problem very fast!